# Cloning drive to drive of same size in Ubuntu Server 12.04LTS

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ubuntu-12.04, disk-cloning

I'm trying to replace a 3.5in hard drive with a 2.5in hard drive inside a 1U server. The drives have the same capacity (250GB, 232GB formatted). It's been years since I've cloned a hard drive, and even then, it was with Windows. Basically, I have the new hard drive mounted in an external dock (it's a bare drive, not an external HDD) and I need to mount it. However, I don't know how I'd go about duplicating the current hard drive's partition scheme and the like. I see a few different ways on the Google, but what's the best way to do this so that I can clone the drive, take out the old one, pop in the new one, and boot up as I did before?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any ghost application will do this for you. The process for each is more or less the same. I personally have used [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php) and  [Norton Ghost](http://download.cnet.com/Norton-Ghost/3000-2242_4-10798.html) if you want to give that a try.

*Note*: I really hate linking people to software on CNET (Norton Ghost) as they try and install so much rubbish on your system, but if you are used to dealing with their downloads then give it a try. I would suggest Clonezilla first just to avoid this issue.